# Cannot edit files with SFTP

Tags: 18.04, permissions, ssh, ftp, sftp

I have a user with `sudo` access (I use Password to login, not SSH key), everything works fine on SSH (I can edit files with sudo)

But on FTP, when editing files it gives me Permission Denied error...

I tried the following on SSH to fix it with no luck:

```
sudo find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;


sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

Any help is appreciated

**Edit:**

The following commands Allowed me to edit on SFTP, is it the only way?

```
sudo find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
```

Comment: Are you accessing the same location on the same server with the same user?

Comment: @Yaron Yes, I only have this user, the file I'm trying to edit is in `/var/www/app/Http/` folder, I was finally able to edit it with SFTP after I gave 666 permission, is it really necessary to give 666?

Comment: @j-doe it looks like it's not the same user, please add the output of `ls -lah` on this folder and also run `whoami`.

Comment: @Yaron `whoami` shows the correct user (mine) , but `ls -lah` shows a lot of files belong to `root` user... why the command I ran above didn't fix this? how do I give ownership of **all** files and folders inside `/var/www/` to my current user? could you please post it as answer?

Comment: I can see that the `Http` folder is owned by `root`, I'm guessing your user is `ubuntu`, you can try and change ownership using `sudo chown -R ubuntu: Http` while you're in `/var/www`.

Comment: @Yaron After running your command, editing works now with 644 permission!!! Thank you!

Comment: I'll add that as a solution so you can vote for it, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the ownership of the files and the containing folder.

Can be solved using `sudo chown -R ubuntu: Http`